# 'Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to post an API.

Here is my code:

```
function update(object){
    var data = '<roblox xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.roblox.com/roblox.xsd"
       version="4">
       <External>null</External><External>nil</External>
       <Item class="StringValue" referent="RBX0">
            <Properties>
                <string name="Name">Notifications</string>
                <string name="Value">'+JSON.stringify(object)+'</string>
            </Properties>
       </Item>
    </roblox>'

    $.post("https://data.roblox.com/Data/Upload.ashx?type=Model&assetid=436257202&length="+data.length,data)

}

update({name:'test'})
```

But it shows error in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://data.roblox.com/data/upload.ashx?type=Model&assetid=436257202&length=406.
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

I think the data is correct, but I am not sure why this error has arisen

Comment: Can you capture what the preflight looks like? In Chrome, at least, you should see an `OPTIONS` request taking place before the `POST`. If the preflight (`OPTIONS`) request is redirecting, you probably need to change the URL you are posting to.

Comment: A preflight should return 200 OK. This is a CORS problem. So google CORS.

Comment: @jacob There are two OPTIONS requests. Does this mean I am using the wrong url?

Comment: The response header probably has a redirect location. That means you _may_ just need to change your URL. Or maybe this API doesn't support CORS, or you have to configure something to enable it.

Comment: I think it is the URL. This previously worked. But they recently changed everything to https

Answer (score 1):

Just piggybacking off of Amazing Aaron's answer, I had a similar issue and can confirm that it was the URL. Try changing all of the cases of `http` to `https`. This should resolve it.