# Can't download file with HTTP request: response for preflight is invalid

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, slack-api

I'm trying to use an HTTP request in JavaScript to retrieve a file from the Slack API. I managed to get the `url_private_download` of the file, but if I try to make an HTTP GET request using that URL, I get an error in the console saying that: `Failed to load url_private_download: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`.

Here's my code:

```
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
   }
  };
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url_private_download, true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + my_slack_token);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*')
  xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: You could try requesting to HTTPS rather than HTTP, if you aren't already?

Comment: The URL already starts with HTTPS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve 'preflight is invalid (redirect)' in CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168773/how-to-resolve-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-in-cors)

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901562/response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-error